# Trouble with batch

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I am trying to search 2 .txt files and display the names of programs that are found in both txt files into a new txt file.  The 2 files that I am searching are in the same folder.

Here's my code:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (Programs_installed.txt) do (
 for /f "tokens=*" %%b in (Bloatware1.txt) do (
  if %%a==%%b (echo %%a >> Bloatware_Found.txt)
 ) 
) 
Bloatware_Found.txt
```

Comment: Please tell us what is the system, what you tried.

Comment: for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (Programs_installed.txt) do (
 for /f "tokens=*" %%b in (Bloatware1.txt) do (if %%a==%%b 

(echo %%a >> Bloatware_Found.txt))
)
Bloatware_Found.txt

Comment: I tried that and it worked 1 time and for some reason it has failed to detect anything and out put it to the Bloatware_Found.txt file even though I made sure that there were matching file names in both text files

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off&cls
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type "Programs_installed.txt"') do (
      for /f "tokens=*" %%b in ('type "Bloatware1.txt"') do if %%a==%%b echo %%a >>"Bloatware_Found.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

Without sample data (a few lines from each file) it's difficult to tell.

A few things that may assist:

`if %%a==%%b` should be

```
if /i "%%a"=="%%b"
```

- the quotes ensure that `"data containing spaces"` is treated as a single string. The `/i` makes the comparison case-insensitive.

Not sure what the final line (as it appears to be) is actually intended to do. It should invoke an instance of your default editor, loading `bloatware_found.txt`.

OR

perhaps you intended

```
(
 for /f ... %%a
   for /f ... %%b
    if ....
)>bloatware_found.txt

which will create a new file containing anything `ECHO`ed from statements invoked by `(..)` - even if it's echoed from a subroutine.
```

Now quite what may happen if you have both the `>>file` and `>samefile` I'll not speculate. Possibly it tries to append the data to the file with the `>>file` and then writes the entire output which was sent to the console (ie. nothing, since the `echo`es were redirected) to a new version of the same file. If so, remove the append-redirection (`>>file`) and all should be restored.

But a possible solution, depending on the available (but unpublished) data sample would be

```
findstr /l /g:bloatware1.txt /i Programs_installed.txt >bloatware_found.txt
```

Comment: Thanks that helped out quite a bit you are the awesome Thank you very much